# Session not using correct variable

Tags: php, session

I have a session that is supposed to carry a variable from one page to another. The session is set, however it does not have the correct value, I need this session to dynamically change.
Here's the code for the viewing page:

```
  // Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

      $query = "SELECT username FROM kaoscraft_user WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
            $username1 = $row['username'];

  // Grab the pm data from the database
  $query = "SELECT `to`, `from`, rank, gender, picture, title, msg FROM kaoscraft_pm WHERE `to` = '$username1' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  $gender = $row['gender'];

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  session_start();
    $reply = $row['from'];
    $_SESSION['reply'] = $row['from'];
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  echo '<div class="vpside">';
    if(!empty($row['picture'])) {
    echo '<img class="pictest" src="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . $row['picture'] . '" alt="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . 'nopic.png' . '" />';
    }
  if(!empty($row['from'])) {
      echo '<p>From:<br />' . $row['from'] . '</p>';
      echo '<a href="reply.php">Reply</a>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['rank'])) {
      echo '<p>Rank:<br />' . $row['rank'] . '</p>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['gender'])){
    echo '<p>Gender:<br /> ' . $row['gender'] . '</p>';
  }  
  echo '</div>';

    if(!empty($row['title'])) {
        echo'<h4><u>' .$row['title']. '</u></h4>';
    }
      if(!empty($row['msg'])) {
      echo '<p class="">' . $row['msg'] . '</p>';
    }
        echo '<div class="sig">';
      if(!empty($row['bio'])) {
      echo '<p>' . $row['bio'] . '</p>';
      }
      echo '</div>';
    echo '</div><br />'; 
    }
  mysqli_close($dbc); 
?>
```

Yes, the query had been executed, and yes `row` is set.

Here's the carry over script:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['reply'])) {
    echo 'value=' . $_SESSION['reply'];
    }
```

Mind you this is a test script and not the script I will actually be using, just in-case you were wondering. and in the second script it is a **SNIPPET** not the **whole code** that is why you do not see `session_start();`

Comment: *...however it does not have the correct value"* --- Which value is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited the question. Please look again

Comment: Try and place `session_start();` at the top instead of where it's now, see if that makes it kick in. I'm asking you do this, before I go over your entire code, and trying to figure out, which value you're expecting. My head's kind of going to mush at this time of night after a day's full of coding. ;-)

Comment: Try and do `$_SESSION['reply'] = $reply;` instead of `$_SESSION['reply'] = $row['from'];` since you already declared it with `$reply = $row['from'];`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That still did not work. What I need it to do is every different message on the page needs to have a different value for `$_SESSION['reply']`

Comment: Well there's no other reference to `$reply` so it's just sitting there in limbo. Try and remove that line `$reply = $row['from'];` altogether. That's all I can come up with. Like I said earlier, my head needs a fresh start and late at this hour, I'm not at my best. If that works, great. If not, then wait for others to come and shed more light on the subject. ;-)

Comment: ... or switch `$_SESSION['reply'] = $row['from'];` to `$row['from'] = $_SESSION['reply'];`

Comment: @Fred-ii- What i mean is I need each reply to use the correct username from the post the reply link is under.

Comment: Ok, well as it stands now, you have `$_SESSION['user_id']` in your query and `session_start();` is below it. `session_start();` needs to be above that in order for your query to work. Ok; when that's done, if you want the correct username then, well you'll need to change `$_SESSION['reply'] = $row['from'];` to `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['from'];` least that's what I think without seeing full table layout/schema.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49337/discussion-between-user3371397-and-fred-ii)